# selenium can't find video player elements on website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

im trying to automate autoplay on this website "https://www.wcofun.net/adventure-time-season-7-episode-24-the-hall-of-egress", the script can find the next episode button but can't find any of the video controller elements, such as the quality controller called

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_bin = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_bin
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.wcofun.net/adventure-time-season-7-episode-24-the-hall-of-egress")

div_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "prev-fln")

# Find the span with class "prev-next" and style "float:right" within the div
span_element = div_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='prev-next' and contains(@style,'float:right')]")

# Find the anchor tag inside the span
a_element = span_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")

a_element.click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 710);")
time.sleep(3)

# Instantiate ActionChains again for the second mouse movement
actions = ActionChains(driver)

x_coord = 590
y_coord = 381
actions.move_by_offset(x_coord, y_coord).click().perform()

# Instantiate ActionChains again for the third mouse movement
actions = ActionChains(driver)

x_coord = 966
y_coord = 559

div_elementa = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-quality-container")


time.sleep(1000)
```

```
<div class="vjs-quality-container"><div class="vjs-quality-dropdown"><ul><li data-code="hd720"><a href="#">HD</a></li><li data-code="hd576"><a href="#">SD</a></li></ul></div><button class="vjs-brand-quality-link">Quality</button></div>
```

heres the element i want selenium to interact with

since this doesnt work, i tried using move_by_offset a second time but it throws a outofbounds exception

i have tried using xpath aswell which doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

A good process to follow is to load page yourself first and see which elements are available on page load, and with which ones you need to interact first so that the content you want becomes available.

Here are steps you'd need to take then:

- since the video is in an iframe, you'll need to wait for it to load
- then, you'll need to switch the context to the iframe
- then you need to click the play button which will make other buttons you're interested in available
- then you can access quality button and other buttons you might be interested in

Code example that follows this process:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_bin = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_bin
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.wcofun.net/adventure-time-season-7-episode-24-the-hall-of-egress")

# Wait for iframe to load
iframe_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

# Switch to the iframe if the video player is within an iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))

# Wait for play button to load
play_button_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-big-play-button")))

# Click play button
play_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-big-play-button")
play_button.click()

time.sleep(10)

# Wait for the quality container to be visible and interactable
quality_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-quality-container")))

# Click on the quality button to open the quality dropdown
quality_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-brand-quality-link")
quality_button.click()

# Wait for the quality options to be visible and interactable
quality_options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".vjs-quality-dropdown li")))

# Choose the desired quality option (e.g., HD)
hd_option = None
for option in quality_options:
    if option.text == "HD":
        hd_option = option
        break

if hd_option:
    hd_option.click()
```